# How to add Menu in android

Tags: android-menu

I want to know about menu.I tried using some codes given in net.It seems simple but can't get output when i run application.I used onCreateOptionMenu and menuinflater.I created a new folder under res and named it as menu and i add item in menu.xml under it.But can't get output.kindly let me know my mistake.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:title="ICON"/>
<item android:id="@+id/text"
    android:title="Text" />
<item android:id="@+id/icontext"
    android:title="Icon and text"
    />
</menu>
```

Activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;

public class Simple extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;                  
    }
}
```

Comment: Post some code of what you have tried. It looks like you already have the right "ingredients". To post the code, you can edit your original question.

Comment: Thanks Heiko Rupp,I edited my question above.let me know how to make visible the menu button in my activity.where i have to change.

Comment: problem solved only after i clicked the menu button in emulator.So anyone try this menu option keep in mind to click the emulator prodefined menu button.Then only your application menu option become visible to you to click.

Comment: divya123: you can put your latest comment into an answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to click the predefined menu button in emulator to make our menu option visible.